# Exponential supremum proof

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

Suppose $S\neq\emptyset$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Define $T=\{e^x:x\in\ S\}$. Show that $sup(T)=e^{sup(S)}$.

To do this I said suppose $x=sup(S)$. Then for any $a\in S$ we have $x\ge a$. Hence $e^x\ge e^a$, so $e^x$ is an upper bound for $T$. Now we need to show it is the least upper bound. This part I struggled with - suppose there is some $y$ for which $e^y$ is an upper bound of $T$. Then we have $e^y\ge e^a$ for any $a\in S$ and so $y\ge a$ for any $a\in S$, proving that $y=x$. Is this an ok proof or have I made a mistake?

I think the first part I did correctly (proving $e^x$ is an upper bound for $T$ where $x=sup(S)$), but I worry I made a mistake for proving that it is the least upper bound.

Comment: How did you conclude that $y = x$?

Comment: Well since $x=sup(S), x\ge a$ for any a in S. Since $y$ has a similar inequality it must be the case that $y=x$(Since we could have a=x)

Comment: @Alidixon244 that’s not true $8\ge 6$ and $7\ge 6$  but $8$ does not equal to $7$

Answer (score 1):

Just because $y\ge a$ and $x\ge a$ does not mean $x=y$, $y$ could be for example $x+1$.
 To prove that $e^x$ is the least upper bound of $T$ you have to show that for any upper bound of $T$ , $M$, $M\ge e^x$,
 To prove this assume that there exists a $M$ such that $e^x>M$ then $e^x>e^k$ for some $k$ so $x>k$ but $x$ is the leats upper bound and $k$ is also an upper bound(since $e^k=M$ implies that $e^k > e^a$ for all $a$ in $S$) contradiction.